# My flag after 8 days still being verified, why so long?

Tags: discussion, flags

I had flagged this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28520788/1841194) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28521043/1841194) as those wasn't real question and answer that might be suitable for other readers.

Today, I have checked my flags history page and I wondered why that flag is taking so much time to be verified?

[image]

Comment: Why did you flag that for moderator attention? The community can handle such posts directly without having to call in the janitors.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You used a custom flag asking for a moderator to handle it.  We've got a backlog of flags to review so it is currently waiting for a moderator to review it and process the flag.

However, if you think this should be closed then you should be using your close votes, instead of flagging for a moderator.  Moderators should only be involved in things that the community cannot handle and this is not one of them.  Your close votes will kick this into the review queue for closure.

Comment: hi bluefeet, I had used my close vote too but nothing happened `:)`

Comment: Close votes go into the Close Review Queue for the community to handle. By flagging for a moderator you are basically saying - _this is urgent and it needs something immediately to happen_. That doesn't apply here so flagging for a moderator is the wrong thing to do.